# Deploy Angular Universal to Shared Hosting without npm or node.js

Tags: node.js, angular, cpanel, angular-universal

I currently have access to an standard cPanel shared hosting, without SSH
I have an angular application running there https://www.rednots.com 
However now I need the app to have server side rendering for Facebook share, I've been using Universal toolkit from https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-toolkit and it works great in local
Now my issue is: can I deploy the Universal app the same way I've deployed the Angular client side app by uploading the dist folder? Do I need node.js installed in the server and run commands? Or is it any workaround so I don't need to use commands?

Comment: No uploading your dist folder will not work. You cant do it without npm or node, angular universal needs to an express server to run which requires node. Your better off using heroku or something to publish your project there are a few angular-universal-heroku-starters out there you can look at

Comment: So the best solution would be to move my project to a Heroku server? I also have laravel as Back end

Answer (score 0):

ng-toolkit is using lambda functions and api gateways to be used by the services.
Technically speaking you only need to deploy the dist folder and everything should work out of the box since you mentioned that you already tested it locally and it works which means that the lambda functions are already deployed and the services are pointing to AWS gateway properly.